# Force Rails 3 dynamic finder to throw RecordNotFound exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, activerecord

Is is possible to force a Rails dynamic finder to throw an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception rather than return `nil` when it cannot find a result?

For example, where a beverage of the name 'Nuka–Cola' does not exist:

```
@not_found = Beverage.find_by_name('Nuka–Cola')
```

Rather than having

```
@not_found == nil
```

Could the

```
.find_by_name('Nuka–Cola')
```

method call throw an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception?

Or am I going to have to check for `nil` and throw the exception manually?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the bang version.

```
@not_found = Beverage.find_by_name!('Nuka–Cola')
```

Comment: Simple and exactly as I would have expected ActiveRecord to implement such a feature.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks a lot, guise

It will be more useful if you are working on some REST API stuffs.
instead of showing the html exception page, render meaningful JSON or XML.

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
 rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found

  def not_found(exception = nil)
    render :json => { :message => exception.message, :request => request.fullpath }, 
                      :status => 404
  end
end
```